# Getting user input and checking if it exists in a list

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am trying to check if a user input as a string exists in a list called categoriesList which appends categories from a text file named categories.txt. If the user inputs a category that then exists in categoriesList my code should be able to print out "Category exists", otherwise "Category doesn't exist".

Here is the code:

```
categoriesList = []
with open("categories.txt", "r") as OpenCategories:
    for category in (OpenCategories):
        categoriesList.append(category)
        while True:
            inputCategories = input("Please enter a category:")
            if inputCategories in categoriesList:
                print("Category exists")
                break
            else:
                print("Category doesn't exist")
                break
```

When I run this code it always outputs Category doesn't exist even if the category I enter actually exists in categoriesList. How would I solve this problem in the code? Furthermore, I want to be able to get one input from the user for entering a category so I don't want "Please enter a category" to come up several times, I just want the code to make it come up just once.

Also, it would be much appreciated if I could know the code on how I would then do all of the above in tkinter as I need to do the above in GUI. I think you need to have labels and allow the user to enter a category in a box on the screen.

I have tried to make code which tries to check a user input exists in a list after getting the input on a tk screen as its not enough for me to just have the check happening in a python console and its not doing it properly, so here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
window=tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(window, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()
label1 = Label(window, text="Please enter a category:")
label1.pack()
entry = Entry(window, width=50)
entry.pack()
def for_button():
       checkUserInput = entry.get()
button = Button(window, text="Check", command=for_button)
button.pack()
for i in categoriesList:
     if button in categoriesList:
         categoryExist = Label(window, text="Category exists")
         categoryExist.pack()
     else:
         categoryNotExist= Label(window, text="Category doesn't exist")
         categoryNotExist.pack()
 window.mainloop()
```

It uses the list categoriesList from the code eariler in the post that was given and I am trying to get the user to enter a category into the text box  on  the tk screen and click "check" button afterwards but before the user can give an input "category doesn't exist" comes up numerous times which is what I don't want the code to be doing.

Comment: One suggestion, especially when `categoriesList` is small, is to instead write `print("Category doesn't exist", categoriesList, inputCategories)`. This might give some more detail as to why it doesnt find the input category in the list.

Comment: _"it would be much appreciated if I could know the code on how I would then do all of the above in tkinter "_ - Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service. The best thing to do is to work through a tkinter tutorial, then come back here when you get stuck on a specific part of the problem.

Comment: The `while` loop should not be inside the `for` loop.  Actually the while loop is not necessary at all.

Answer (score -1):

When you read from a textfile you also read special characters such as `'\n'` therefore this must be removed. This can be done as shown in the code below.

I also slightly tweaked you loop layout as you don't want to have the `while` loop inside the `for` loop - otherwise you would be searching the list before all categories had been added.

```
categoriesList = []
with open("categories.txt", "r") as OpenCategories:
    for category in (OpenCategories):
        categoriesList.append(category.strip()) #remove newline, tabs etc
    
inputCategories = input("Please enter a category:")
if inputCategories in categoriesList:
    print("Category exists")
else:
    print("Category doesn't exist")
```

You may also want to remove any spaces `' '` from your category list. This could be done by replacing

`category.strip()`

with

`category.strip().replace(' ','')`

You may also want to make the inputted variable and the category all lowercase for easier comparison. This can be done using the `lower` function on the string.

e.g. `inputCategories = inputCategories.lower()`

Answer (score -1):

The while loop should not be inside the for loop and the while loop is not necessary at all:

```py
with open("categories.txt", "r") as OpenCategories:
    categoriesList = OpenCategories.read().splitlines()

# don't need the while loop
inputCategories = input("Please enter a category:")
if inputCategories in categoriesList:
    print("Category exists")
else:
    print("Category doesn't exist")
```

---

For your updated code using GUI, you need to put the checking inside `for_button()` function:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# load category list from file
with open("categories.txt") as OpenCategories:
    categoriesList = OpenCategories.read().splitlines()

window = tk.Tk()

label1 = tk.Label(window, text="Please enter a category:")
label1.pack()

# user input category
entry = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
entry.pack()

def for_button():
    checkUserInput = entry.get()
    if checkUserInput in categoriesList:
        result.config(text="Category exists", fg="green")
    else:
        result.config(text="Category doesn't exist", fg="red")

button = tk.Button(window, text="Check", command=for_button)
button.pack()

# label for check result
result = tk.Label(window)
result.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would you get a user input for a category from the entry box that may have entered all in lowercase letters and make it all uppercase letters because that's how I have the categories in the text file? This means  that if the user enters a category all in lowercase letters and it exists in the text file  the code displays "category doesn't exist" when it actually does. I am just trying to make the code more flexible for more than one type of input and I have tried to use StringVar() associated with a variable and textvariable in the line of code for "check" button but an error comes up.

Comment: If the categories stored in file are all in uppercase, then use `checkUserInput = entry.get().upper()`.

Comment: Okay I have tried entry.get().upper() and it works